# DetailedView and expiring items not working in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a simple application, where elements should expire automatically after 5 minutes.

In models.py I have the following:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def calc_default_expire():
    return timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(minutes=5)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(default=calc_default_expire)
    ...
```

In my views.py, I have the following:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .models import MyModel
from django.utils import timezone


class MyModelDetail(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(expire_date__gt=timezone.now())
```

I'm getting some strange behaviour. Even after 5 minutes, when I call the url of the expired item, it still gets returned (http code 200).

However, when I restart the builtin django dev server, and call the url again, I'm getting a 404, which is the desired result.

I see two possible causes:

- the built-in webserver is caching some stuff (I doubt this to be honest, I could not find anything in the docs that mentions this behaviour)
- I'm doing something wrong in my queryset filter (but I'm not seeing it).

Expire_date seems to be calculated correctly when I add new items. Anyone got a clue what I'm missing here?

`USE_TZ = True` in my settings.py BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes perfect sense, since the `timezone.now()` is evalated once, when you start the server. After that, it will thus each time query with the same datetime.

You can use [**`Now()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#now) instead, which will then let the database determine the time:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class MyModelDetail(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(expire_date__gt=Now())
```

It will thus not evaluate the time at the moment you call `Now()`, but use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (or some other function the database provides) each time you make the query.

An alternative is to postpone the query, and thus use `get_queryset` to construct a queryset each time:

```
class MyModelDetail(DetailView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.filter(expire_date__gt=timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `timezone.now()` in the queryset attribute of your view is evaluated at import time and never changed.

Whenever you have anything dynamic in the queryset, or indeed any class-level attribute, you should move it into a method:

```
class MyModelDetail(DetailView):
    def get_queryset(self): 
        return AppFile.objects.filter(expire_date__gt=timezone.now())
```

(Note, I don't understand why you defined both model and queryset, and even less why you used different models for each; the model attribute is ignored if you define the queryset.)

Comment: was changing some stuff from the copypaste, and AppFile should have been MyModel. I fixed this in the original question now. Thanks for pointing this out. And yes, I started with "model" and added additional constraints later via query_set. Should have removed the "model" attribute.